# Wrapping a method from parent class

Tags: python

I am using [Python.Net](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html) to embed python in C#. In my python script, a python class inherits a C# class:

```
# algo.py:
class MyCustomAlgo(QCAlgorithm):
    def Initialize(self):
        self.AddUniverse(selector)
```

AddUniverse method is defined at the parent class QCAlgorithm (C#).

During runtime, the engine passes selector to AddUniverse. The issue is right overload for that selector type is not found. In order to solve this issue, I have added a new AddMethod that overrides the inherited one:

```
# helper.py:
def AddUniverse(self, selector):
    selector = Func[DateTime, IEnumerable[String]](selector)
    super(self.__class__, self).AddUniverse(selector)
```

If I add this code snippet into the first, it works just fine. However, I need to have these code snippets in two different files (e.g.: algo.py and helper.py).

I tried using PyObject.SetAttr method, but it threw an exception saying that        "attribute is read-only". Alternately I can use this method to create a "Add_Universe" method based on the wrapper.

However the goal is to keep the exact signature: `self.AddUniverse(selector)`.

Is that possible? How would you do it?

Comment: FYI, `super(self.__class__, self)` is wrong, and will not work correctly if you ever actually have a subclass that wraps `AddUniverse` (you'll get stack overflow from infinite recursion). If you're on Python 3, just use `super()` without arguments; if you're on Python 2, you must explicitly name the class that you're defining this `AddUniverse` in, e.g. `super(MyCustomAlgo, self)`. You _CANNOT_ use `self.__class__` here without breaking further subclassing.

Comment: So how would I make it universal?
In other words, I don't know what the class name might be. I am using _MyCustomAlgo_, but another person may use _CrazyTradingIdea_...

Comment: Don't monkey-patch methods into classes. Make a mixin class, and let people inherit from it. Or more hackily, make an `AddUniverse` factory function that accepts the class it's being added to as an argument, and returns a new closure over `AddUniverse` that is suitable for monkey-patching into a class, used like: `MyCustomAlgo.AddUniverse = AddUniverseFactory(MyCustomAlgo)`, where the factory accepts `cls` as an argument, and uses `super(cls, self)`.